# Tooltip not showing up d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have simple tooltip question but I couldn't find the solution.
The codes below draw a doughnut chart. When user mouseovers a segment of pie, the tooltip should pop up in the middle of doughnut. But I don't know why it does not work here. Can anyone help to point out the problem? Here is [JSbins](https://jsbin.com/dihovilabe/edit?html,css,js,output)

If I change the line 36 to `d3.select(#pieChart)`, the tooltip works. However, for some reasons, I want the tooltip to append on svg.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to append a div inside svg element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595813/is-it-possible-to-append-a-div-inside-svg-element)

Comment: Like @Paul said, you can't use a `div` element inside an `svg`. What you want is to use a `g` (group) element and then append `text` elements to that, setting `.attr("y", <value>)` to offset them vertically. Then all you'll have to change is `.html(...)` to `.text(...)` when you update the tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not used JSBin a lot so I used JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/0qgzLk2L/

You can't append a div to svg so you have to create a container like so :

```
 var svgContainer = d3.select('#pieChart');
```

And then append the svg to this :

```
var svg = svgContainer.append('svg')
```

And now use the container for the tooltips :

```
var tooltip = svgContainer
      .append('div')
```