# get the position details of a div inside an svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I have included div's inside svg using foreignObject (I tried to use rect instead of div's, [as in this example](http://comexile.blogspot.com/2016/08/simple-mapping-tool-with-d3.html), but extendability-wise, the best option is div).

I want to add an svg circle at the end of each div of a particular class. The above example adds circles to all the elements, but now I want to filter them with a class selector. How can I achieve this with d3?

```
var leafnodes = new Array();
d3.select("#input-container-div").selectAll(".leaf")
    .each(function () {
        leafnodes.push(d3.select(this).style("top"));
     });
```

I used the above code but results in "0px" since the CSS of it does not define a value for "top".

I also tried the solution on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag), but for some reason it does not work.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595813/is-it-possible-to-append-a-div-inside-svg-element

Comment: @arthur_3589897 I went through it when I decided to use rect's instead of div's, but I had to use divs (the content divs are to be written by a separate recursive method later, which needs divs).

Comment: can you share a working jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you explain in more details why you need to use foreignObject?

Comment: @ksav the only way to put a div inside an SVG is by using `foreignObject`.

Answer (score 2):

As you appended the divs using `foreignObject`, you set the x and y values to `foreignObject`, not to the divs. So, you need to get the values selecting the foreign objects, which are the parents of the divs.

Getting the "x" value of the parent (`foreignObject`) of each div:

```
var leafnodes = new Array();
d3.select("#input-container-div").selectAll(".leaf")
    .each(function () {
        leafnodes.push(d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("x"));
    });
```

For instance, giving this simple SVG, we can console.log the x and y positions:

```js
var leafnodes = new Array();
d3.select("svg").selectAll("div")
    .each(function () {
     leafnodes.push({x: d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("x"),
y: d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("y")});
    });

console.log(JSON.stringify(leafnodes))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300" style="border:1px red solid">
    <foreignobject x="40" y="20" width="100" height="100">
        <div style="border:1px green solid">I'm a div inside a SVG.</div>                
    </foreignobject>
    <foreignobject x="300" y="120" width="100" height="100">
        <div style="border:1px green solid">I'm another div inside a SVG.</div>                
     </foreignobject>
</svg>
```

Comment: So basically for this method, each div must have a foreign object with specified position details right?

Comment: Yes. If your foreignObjects don't have any x or y value, you still can get the positions using a workaround: put your SVG inside a div and get the offsetTop and offsetLeft of the inner divs and the outer (container) div. Subtracting the values gives you the x and y positions.