# How to embed html code between SVG tags

Tags: css, html, svg, vml

My application was in VML which allowed me to embed html between VML tags. But VML only supports till IE-8. Now I have converted VML to SVG using **vectorconverter**. But SVG doesn't allows to embed html tag between the SVG tags. After searching on **stack** and **google** I came across for using **foreignobject** tags, However it also only supports till IE-8. I also tried using **switch** tag placing above foreignobject  tags but it to did not worked. Is there any way where I can embed the html code between SVG tags ie below. Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML inside SVG</title>
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body>        
    <svg width="500" height="300" style="border:1px red solid">
        <switch>
        <foreignobject class="node" x="46" y="22" width="100" height="100">

                <div style="border:1px green solid">I'm a div inside a SVG.</div>                
        </foreignobject>
        </switch>
    </svg>
    <div>Interesting! But you a Foreign Object.</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can probably accomplish what you are using the SVG for in CSS now

Comment: can you give me one example

Comment: Give me an example of what you are trying to do and I might be able to

Comment: You can also take the above code example so that I can get an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using CSS only. See the attached jsFiddle. I have left your example in for reference above the html/css implementation.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwtb9w5s/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <span>I'm a div inside a SVG.</span>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  border:1px red solid
}

.inner {
  border:1px green solid;
  position: relative;
  top: 22px;
  left: 46px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: but its not supported in Internet explorer if we are using foreignobject

Comment: It doesn't use SVG or foreign objects at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a duplicate of: [is it possible to append a div inside svg element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595813/is-it-possible-to-append-a-div-inside-svg-element)

> You can't append HTML to SVG (technically you can with foreignObject, but it's a rabbit hole). Furthermore, visible elements in SVG can't be nested, so elements such as circle, rect, path and such can't have children elements.

Comment: But is there any workaround. As I have div, span, table etc tags, which is not possible to write in SVG tags even after converting from html to SVG

Comment: You cant convert HTML to SVG. SVG seems to be nearly the same like HTML but it isnt. Its just another markup language (like XML). Workarounds depend on what you are trying to accomplish. On solution would be to `position` the elements `relative` or `absolute` above your `<svg>`