# How to create a v-tooltip on svg using vuetifyjs

Tags: javascript, svg, vuejs2, vuetify.js

**Here's a piece of my SVG:**

```
<g id="g05">    
    <polygon class="st2" points="224.8,256.4 309.9,390.6 224.8,517.5 144.1,386.2" filter="url(#dropshadow)"/>   
    <defs>      
        <filter id="dropshadow">            
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>             
            <feOffset dx="3" dy="2"/>           
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"/>            
            </feComponentTransfer>          
            <feMerge> 
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>           
            </feMerge>      
         </filter>  
    </defs> 
</g>
```

**And this is created `<v-tooltip>`:**

```
<v-tooltip v-model="show" top color="cyan lighten-2">
    <v-btn icon slot="activator" fab large>
      <v-icon color="red darken-1">home</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <span class="display-2">Продвижение</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

How to create a `v-tooltip` on my svg? I'm trying to nest it into my `v-tooltip` but it doesn't seem to work.

**Update:**
My SVG looks like this: 
[image]

And when I hover a part of a SVG it has to show me a tooltip. A code of a part of a SVG file I shared at the top.

Comment: This might be related (using `foreignObject` to nest a div inside of an svg) https://stackoverflow.com/a/17596084/184746

Comment: Unfortunately that topic couldn't hep me...

Comment: thank u for your help. I'm gonna try to go this way.

Comment: I just looked at the docs for vuetify, it should work to wrap any element - if you want to wrap the whole SVG that should be possible `<v-tooltip><svg> ... </svg></v-tooltip>`. Is this not what you're trying to achieve? Can you update the question to be more clear about where the tooltip should be?

Comment: @caesay Updated...

Answer (score 0):

i think i had the same issue: i had to provide tooltips for single svg elements (path, circle, etc...) and solved it in a "hacky" way:

i settled the [v-tooltip](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/) template as explained on the official documentation, but in a [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) tag

then moved the svg elements out of the foreignObject on tooltip [mount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)