# How to get tippy.js to use individual svg elements as targets when the SVG is embedded in an HTML object tag?

Tags: javascript, svg, tippyjs

I have an svg embedded in HTML using an object tag

```
<div id="svgDiv">
<object id="svgObjectElement" data="mysvg.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
            Your browser doesn't support SVG.
</object>
</div>
```

I want to use the tippy.js library to provide tooltips for circles in my svg, but I can't seem to get tippy to use the circles in mysvg as targets. If the svg is in the HTML (like this line element) it works great.

HTML:

```
<svg height="50" width="50"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="50" y2="50" style="stroke:tomato;stroke-width:5"></line></svg>
<div id="svgDiv">
<object id="svgObjectElement" data="mysvg.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
            Your browser doesn't support SVG.
</object>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
tippy('line', {
    content: 'Custom Line Tooltip',
})
```

I have tried the following JavaScript where circle1 is the id of a circle in the svg but it doesn't work:

```
var svgDocument = document.getElementById("svgObjectElement").contentDocument;
var element = svgDocument.getElementById("circle1");
tippy(element, {
    content: 'Custom circle Tooltip',
});
```

I have also tried

```
var svgDocumentElement= document.getElementById("svgObjectElement").contentDocument.documentElement;
var element = svgDocumentElement.getElementById("circle1");
tippy(element, {
    content: 'Custom circle Tooltip',
});
```

which doesn't work. I am using Chrome if that is relevant. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Tippy.js temporarily appends a `div` element at the end of `body` tag, inside body tag itself. The problem with `svg` elements is that they neither have `body` tag nor they support the `div` tag and are therefore not going to show up. See here: [Is it possible to append a div inside an SVG element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595813/is-it-possible-to-append-a-div-inside-an-svg-element)

If Tippy.js were able to detect that it is inside an `svg` document it could wrap the `div` inside `foreignobject` tag (which would most probably solve the issue).

One more thing to notice is that you would also have to include Tippy.js library directly into the `svg` document itself like this `<script xlink:href="../js/tippy.min.js"></script>`. But even then you will get an error because Tippy.js is trying to reference elements which do not exist `head`, `body`, etc.

So, to me, the best approach for this problem is to create an overlay `div` over your `circle1` element outside of the `svg` object and add a tooltip to that `div`. Hint: [How to overlay one div over another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div)