# D3.js cant display a tooltip

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, data-visualization

I'm trying to add a tooltip each time when hovering circles in my line chart.
As you can see in the picture below tooltip is exist in dom but I can't display it. Here I recreated my problem in sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-browser-t38ud6?file=/src/App.js

[image]

```
const tooltip = d3
  .select(d3Chart.current)
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", "0")
  .style("background-color", "red")
  .html(`<p>test</p>`);

const mouseover = function (d) {
  console.log("tooltip");
  tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0.9);
};

svg
  .append('g')
  .selectAll('dot')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function (d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .attr('cy', function (d) {
    return y(d.balance);
  })
  .attr('r', 5)
  .attr('fill', '#69b3a2')
  .on('mouseover', mouseover);
```

Comment: An HTML `div` cannot be used inside `svg`, c.f. : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17596084

Comment: Do you need to apply css styles to the tooltip?

Comment: @diedu I need to display a tooltip , you can check in sandbox link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this [article](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369), and you just need to move the div outside the svg

- create a ref to select the tooltip div

```
const tooltipRef = useRef();
```

- add it to the HTML

```
   ...
      </button>
      <div className="tooltip" ref={tooltipRef} />
      <svg id="chart" ref={d3Chart}></svg>
   ...
```

- And change its style on the mouse events

```
    const mouseover = function (event, d) {
      console.log(d);
      const tooltipDiv = tooltipRef.current;
      if (tooltipDiv) {
        d3.select(tooltipDiv).transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0.9);
        d3.select(tooltipDiv)
          .html(d.balance)
          // TODO: some logic when the tooltip could go out from container
          .style("left", event.pageX + "px")
          .style("top", event.pageY - 28 + "px");
      }
    };

    const mouseout = () => {
      const tooltipDiv = tooltipRef.current;
      if (tooltipDiv) {
        d3.select(tooltipDiv).transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);
      }
    };

    ...

      .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cloud-tsu6sj?file=/src/App.js

Notice there are some styles for the tooltip in `styles.css`